# Instantiate Class and Declare Variables in One Line

Tags: php, class, instantiation

Is there a way to instantiate a class and define the variables all on one line? Instantiating it, then defining all the variables, then calling it, is taking up almost as many lines as the raw html code would by itself.

I have a class like so:

```
class Gallery {
    public $image;
    public $text;
    public $heading;
    public $link;

    public function Item() {
        echo '
        <div class="gallery_item">
            <div class="gallery_image">
                <img src="' . $this->image . '">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_text">
                <h3> ' . $this->heading . '</h3>
                <p> ' . $this->text . '</p>
                <a href="' . $this->link . '">View Live Site</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

And then I call it by using:

```
<?php
            $Gallery_1 = new Gallery();
            $Gallery_1->image = "img/test.jpg";
            $Gallery_1->heading = "Test Object";
            $Gallery_1->text = "This is a sample text description for the gallery items. It can be long or short";
            $Gallery_1->link ="#";
            $Gallery_1->Item();
        ?>
```

Can I do something like below instead? The below code doesn't work, but is there something similar?

```
$Gallery_1 = new Gallery(image->"img/test.jpg", heading->"test", text->"text", link->"#");
$Gallery_1-Item();
```

Comment: add arguments inside your constructor

Comment: Yes, i was just thinking about Kwargs or args from python and wondering if I could do the same thing here. Could you give me an example of the proper syntax?

Comment: sometimes i read questions here that seem perfectly legitimate for any beginner to ask but for some odd reason they are downvoted without explanation or criticism.  i upvoted this one to help balance the mysterious bad mindedness.

Comment: Thanks. No idea why it would be downvoted. While I'm not a beginner to PHP, I've never used classes before and want to start understanding them more. I figured using them often will help with the comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to feed your own values, use your constructor to setup the properties in the arguments:

```
class Gallery 
{
    public $image;
    public $text;
    public $heading;
    public $link;

    public function __construct($image, $text, $heading, $link) // arguments
    {
        $this->image = $image;
        $this->text = $text;
        $this->heading = $heading;
        $this->link = $link;
    }

    public function Item()
    // rest of your codes
```

So that when you instantiate, just fill up the arguments:

```
$gallery = new Gallery('img/test.jpg', 'test', 'text', 'link#');
$gallery->Item(); // echoes the html markup,
```

Comment: @Longblog this will also work if you try to tweak it into an array argument form, im glad this helped

Comment: @Longblog no problem at all, just glad i was able to help

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way by putting a `__construct` function within your class.

```
public function __construct()
 {
    $this->image = "img/test.jpg";
    $this->heading = "Test Object";
    $this->text = "This is a sample text description for the gallery";
    $this->link ="#";    
 }
```

Then just create instance of your **Gallery** class,

```
    //will call the __construct method internally 
    $Gallery_1 = new Gallery(); 
    $Gallery_1->Item();
```

**EDIT:** As per your comment

```
  public function __construct($image,$heading,$text,$link) 
  {
    $this->image = $image;
    $this->heading = $heading;
    $this->text = $text;
    $this->link =link;    
  }

  $image = "img/test.jpg";
  $heading = "Test Object";
  $text = "This is a sample text description for the gallery";
  $link ="#"; 

  $Gallery_1 = new Gallery($image,$heading,$text,$link);.
  $Gallery_1->Item();
```

Comment: Well the point of the Class is that I need to construct many different gallery items which will all have different images, text, etc. Where do I put the variables for the new object in your method?

Comment: Great thank you! Ghost put the same answer up too. Who do I give the money to?

Comment: @Longblog, this is  up to you but my reputation is less than ghost.

Comment: After looking at both answers I'm going to mark his correct because I feel like the coding is a a bit more clear. I really do appreciate your help though. Thanks again!

Comment: @Longblog No Prob. i was not just indented code perfectly, Anyways best of luck .